# No Default Ciphers attribute in urllib3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, urllib

Here's an odd one in python 3.6, Mac OS X 10.14.3. In python (installed via Homebrew), I type:

```
import requests
print(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS)
```

and python yells at me:

```
AttributeError: module 'requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS'
```

Yet when I ask openssl the same:

```
openssl ciphers `python -c "import requests; print(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS)"`
```

I get a nice long list of all the ciphers on the system.

Does anyone know how to get python and openssl to play nicely in this example and see the cipher list? openssl, python, urllib3, etc. are all installed and up to date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out requests was badly out of date after all. Fixed!

Comment: Exactly how did you fix it? From which to which version did you upgrade it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to reproduce the error.

- python 3.8.16
- requests 2.30.0

it work fine for me after downgrade to requests==2.28.2

Hope it helps